# Mockito perform anyInt() ,excluding zero

Tags: java, integer, range, mockito, zero

Have following expression:

```
when(restResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(anyInt());
```

It's needed to rework this expression for `anyInt()` means "**any Integer except** `0`",
 due to `0` is reserved for another logic.

I'm asking, because it will not graceful to specify 'magic number' within `thenReturn()`.

Comment: `anyInt()` returns `0`, though. I would recommend just using a magic number, and if needed use multiple to cover all cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`anyInt()` is not appropriate for `thenReturn`. `anyInt` is used for argument matching within `when(myMock.myMethod(anyInt()))`. Your `thenReturn` should look like `thenReturn(1)`.

See javadocs in [Matchers](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html)

Comment: John , I have no information about status codes values.About zero only.It means that status=1 or any other could not exist, so could confuse test users.It will be nice to specify something lika range of numbers,excluding zero.

Comment: @sergionni You could do one test where it returns 0, verify that you enter some kind of error state, and then do another with some non-zero number and verify it works correctly? I think doing that and adding comments would be fine for test users to understand

Comment: How would a method that returns `int` return a `range of values`? I don't think you understand how mocking works. You should be testing how your code behaved when called code returns various values. As `radar` suggests, add one test per value that you expect to support and maybe one test with a value that you don't support.